# How to resample data using the Snowpark API for Python

Tags: python, dataframe, resample, snowpark

I am trying to resample some quarterly data in Snowflake into daily data using Snowpark, I have some code that accomplishes this in PySpark; however, it seems that the function "explode()" does not have support in Snowpark.

```
# define function to create date range
def date_range(t1, t2, step=60*60*24):
    """Return a list of equally spaced points between t1 and t2 with stepsize step."""
    return [t1 + step*x for x in range(int((t2-t1)/step)+1)]


def resample(df, date_column='REPORTING_DATE', groupby='ID'):

    # define udf
    date_range_udf = udf(date_range)
    
    # obtain min and max of time period for each group
    df_base = df.groupBy(groupby)\
                .agg(F.min(date_column).cast('integer').alias('epoch_min')).select('epoch_min', F.current_timestamp().cast('integer').alias('epoch_max'))

    # generate timegrid and explode
    df_base = df_base.withColumn(date_column, F.explode(date_range_udf("epoch_min", "epoch_max")))\
                 .drop('epoch_min', 'epoch_max')
    
    # convert epoch to timestamp
    df_base = df_base.withColumn(date_column, F.date_format(df_base[date_column].cast(dataType=T.TimestampType()), 'yyyy-MM-dd')).orderBy(date_column, ascending=True)
    
    # outer left join on reporting_date to resample data
    df = df_base.join(df, [date_column], 'leftouter')
    
    # window for forward fill
    window = Window.orderBy(date_column).partitionBy(groupby).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
    
    # apply forward fill to all columns
    for column in df.columns:
        df = df.withColumn(column, F.last(column, ignorenulls=True).over(window))

    return df
```

Could somebody suggest an alternative / provide a sample piece of code to help me out. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I created an small example:

```
# coding=utf-8
from snowflake.snowpark import Session

from snowflake.snowpark.functions import udf, col, month, sql_expr
from snowflake.snowpark import functions as F
from snowflake.snowpark.types import StringType, IntegerType, StructType, StructField, ArrayType
from snowflake.snowpark import DataFrame
import os
connection_parameters = {
    "account": os.environ["SNOW_ACCOUNT"],
    "user": os.environ["SNOW_USER"],
    "password": os.environ["SNOW_PASSWORD"],
    "role": os.environ["SNOW_ROLE"],
    "warehouse": os.environ["SNOW_WAREHOUSE"],
    "database": os.environ["SNOW_DATABASE"],
    "schema": os.environ.get("SNOW_SCHEMA")
}
session = Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()
# define function to create date range
def date_range(t1, t2, step=60*60*24):
    """Return a list of equally spaced points between t1 and t2 with stepsize step."""
    return [t1 + step*x for x in range(int((t2-t1)/step)+1)]
data=[(1664627688,1664973288),(1641040488,1664973288)] 
schema = StructType([
   StructField("epoch_min", IntegerType(), True),
   StructField("epoch_max", IntegerType(), True)])
df=session.createDataFrame(data,schema).toDF("epoch_min","epoch_max") 
date_range_udf = udf(date_range,input_types=[IntegerType(),IntegerType()], return_type=ArrayType())
df.withColumn('REPORTING_DATE',date_range_udf(col("epoch_min"), col("epoch_max"))).show()
# Adding a new method
def withColumnExplode(self,colname,expr):
    return self.join_table_function('flatten',date_range_udf(col("epoch_min"), col("epoch_max"))).drop(["SEQ","KEY","PATH","INDEX","THIS"]).rename("VALUE",colname)
DataFrame.withColumnExplode = withColumnExplode

df.withColumnExplode('REPORTING_DATE',date_range_udf(col("epoch_min"), col("epoch_max")))\
                 .drop('epoch_min', 'epoch_max').show(20)
```

Is this what you wanted?